# Replace words not in a dict to <unk>

Tags: python, string

I have a dictionary (with 10k+ words) and a passage (with 10M+ words). I want to replace all words which don't appear in the dictionary with `<unk>`.

I tried `str.maketrans` but its key should be a single char.

Then I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348578/5634636 but the regex is extremely slow.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: I think you'll have to follow a similar approach as the solution you listed. But instead of iterating a list, a `set` is way faster in my experience to check for membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We break down the problem into two parts :

- Given the list of words, `passage`, find the indices, i for which `passage[i]` is not in another list of words `dictionary`.
- Then simpy put `<unk>` at those indices.

The, major work is required in 1. To do that, we first convert the list of strings to 2D numpy arrays, so that we can carry out the operations efficiently. Also, we sort the dictionary which is required below in binary search. Also, we pad the dictionary with 0s to have the same number of columns as `passage_enc`.

```
# assume passage, dictionary are initially lists of words
passage = np.array(passage)  # np array of dtype='<U4'
passage_enc = passage.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, passage.itemsize)[:, ::4]  # 2D np array of size len(passage) x max(len(x) for x in passage), with ords of chars

dictionary = np.array(dictionary)
dictionary = np.sort(dictionary)    
dictionary_enc = dictionary.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, dictionary.itemsize)[:, ::4]
pad = np.zeros((len(dictionary), passage_enc.shape[1] - dictionary_enc.shape[1]))    
dictionary_enc = np.hstack([dictionary_enc, pad]).astype(np.uint8)
```

Then we just iterate over passage, and check if the string(now an array) is in dictionary. It will take O(n * m), n, m being the sizes of passage and dictionary respectively.
But, we can improve this by sorting dictionary before hand and doing a binary search in that. So, it becomes O(n * logm).

Also, we JIT compile the code to make it faster. Below, I use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org).

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(cache=True)  # cache as being used multiple times
def smaller(a, b):
    n = len(a)
    i = 0
    while(i<n and a[i] == b[i]):
        i+=1
    if(i==n):
        return False
    return a[i] < b[i]

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def bin_index(array, item):
    first, last = 0, len(array) - 1

    while first <= last:
        mid = (first + last) // 2
        if np.all(array[mid] == item):
            return mid

        if smaller(item, array[mid]):
            last = mid - 1
        else:
            first = mid + 1

    return -1

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def replace(dictionary, passage):
    unknown_indices = []
    n = len(passage)
    for i in range(n):
        ind = bin_index(dictionary, passage[i])
        if(ind == -1):
            unknown_indices.append(i)
    return unknown_indices
```

Check it on sample data

```
import nltk
emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-emma.txt')
passage = np.array(emma)
passage = np.repeat(passage, 50)  # bloat coprus to have around 10mil words
passage_enc = passage.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, passage.itemsize)[:, ::4]

persuasion = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt')
dictionary = np.array(persuasion)
dictionary = np.sort(dictionary)  # sort for binary search

dictionary_enc = dictionary.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, dictionary.itemsize)[:, ::4]
pad = np.zeros((len(dictionary), passage_enc.shape[1] - dictionary_enc.shape[1]))

dictionary_enc = np.hstack([dictionary_enc, pad]).astype(np.uint8)  # pad with zeros so as to make dictionary_enc and passage_enc of same shape[1]
```

Size of both passage and dictionary, finally come out to be of the order the OP require, for timing purposes. This call :

```
unknown_indices = replace(dictionary_enc, passage_enc)
```

takes 17.028s(including the preprocessing time, obviously not including the time to load the corpora) on my 8 core, 16 G system.

Then, it is simple:

```
passage[unknown_indices] = "<unk>"
```

P.S : I guess, we can get a bit more speed by using `parallel=True` in the njit decorator for `replace`. I am getting some weird error in that, will edit if I am able to sort it out.